# Redmine custom logo not appearing

Tags: redmine

I have installed Redmine and I've been playing around with a few themes. I am having trouble installing a custom logo. I add the new file in the correct folder and reference it in the correct stylesheet but when I inspect it in the browser it says "Failed to load the given URL"

I also tried making changes to the base.html.erb file and this did not show up either.

Simple changes to the stylesheet do work however.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Restarting the webserver allowed the changes made to base.html.erb to show but I still can't see any new images I have added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, doing anything with Redmine customization is not easy but I finally got it. I followed this tutorial, http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Howto_add_a_logo_to_your_Redmine_banner

However this did not actually work on my system so I added a few commands of my own. If these commands do not work then try adding sudo in front of them. THis will prompt you for the admin password.

Near the end, the tut tells you to do this in command line:

```
chown redmine:redmine /opt/redmine/public/images/logo.png
```

Now I am using Apache so my path would look more like this

```
chown apache:apache /var/www/redmine/public/images/logo.png
```

Anyway I tried that and it still had no effect, now the additions I was doing was either under public/images or public/themes so I chose to just target the public folder. This may be bad practice when going live but I am only working locally on a virtual machine.

Here is what worked:

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/redmine/public

chmod -R 775 apache:apache /var/www/redmine/public
```

The -R stands for recursive so it effects the child files too. chmod 775 allows read, write, execute permission for Owner & Group, and only read, execute permissions for Other.

Restart your server after that (the command could be slightly different depending on your setup, refer to the tut)

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

This was very confusing for me at first so let me know if anyone needs more clarification on the subject. I am using Redmine installed on a CentOS virtual box.